# OSX terminal weird prefix

Tags: macos, unix

I noticed that I have some weird prefix in my bash terminal - unknown-MACADDRESS. I think in all unix terminals it is suppose to be host name and login. I've tried go to sharing and change my host name in there, but `unknown-` stays in terminal.

[image]

Not sure where problem is, do you know how to change it?

Thanks a lot for any help!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `hostname` command

```
$ sudo hostname dan
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved it. One thing to remember - you need restart your terminal in order changes to be applied!

Comment: The changes are applied as soon as you do it.  The "changes" you're referring to are in the shell prompt, so logging out and back in should fix that, as well as `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: You probably didn't need the `hostname` command; changing the name in `System Preferences -> Sharing` is the right thing to do. But you do need to refresh the value in the shell, by either opening a new terminal window or sourcing the right shell startup file or restarting the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

For me this: `scutil --set HostName yourname` changed the name and it works even after a restart.